# Disconnect Call In-progress on android

Tags: android, telephony

I read somewhere that you can only programatically 'hang-up' a call in progress or stop an outgoing call in android froyo. If you try to do it in anything higher it will not work?

eg. telephonyService.endCall()
doesnt work in gingerbread???

Answer (score 0):

`TelephonyService` is not part of the public Android SDK.

The exploit was to use reflection to access the class. On Gingerbread and higher, this was fixed by requiring a signature-protected permission to use the class.

Comment: Given Root access to the phone is there a way to get around / work with that requirement?